# How do I handle multiple sprites collisions when there are >10 sprites?

Tags: python, sprite, pygame, collision

I making a small program to animate the astar algorithm. If you look at the image, there are lots of yellow cars moving around. Those can collide at any moment, could be just one or all of them could just stupidly crash into each other.

How do I detect all of those collisions? How do I find out which specific car has crash into which other car?

The way I want to handle each collision is to either let them crash, or have one car stop, letting the other car calculate a route around the stopped car.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An even cheaper solution would be to use the `itertools` module to only collide car combinations:

```
import itertools

for c1 in cars:
    collides_environment(c1)

for c1, c2 in itertools.combinations(cars):
    collides(c1, c2)
```

If you use this method, you will collide pairs of cars only once and will not collide cars with themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the class car, and all the instances in a cars list:

```
for c1 in cars:
    collides_environment(c1)
    for c2 in cars:
        collides(c1,c2)
```

You are using pygame, and the cars are more or less a square. For the colliding check you can use the function `collideRect`: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#Rect.colliderect

Comment: i was actually doing that, iterate through the whole list. i was hoping that there was a nicer way of doing this. eventually i plan to add on >200 cars to sort of simulate astar in nyc.

Comment: On that case you may want to check this discussion: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10202/quad-trees-grid-based-collision-putting-logic-into-action

Comment: There are sprite collision functions in : http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite . Even with 200 cars, you don't have to check for all collisions. You can compare just the cars in a sub-grid. ( QuadTrees ).